# Disable 'cannot resolve corresponding jni functions warning when using env->registernatives

Tags: java, android

I use env->RegisterNatives() load cpp file. When using env->RegisterNatives(), the programmer need not add the long signature extern "C" JNIEXPORT  JNICALL (). When env->RegisterNatives() executed successfully, we can use it directly. But some IDEs ask user to add the signature again. How to disable it.

```
    static{
System.loadLibrary('lib');
}

//These signature is correct, but Android Studio and some IDEs says: "cannot resolve corresponding jni functions"
public native void xxx();
public native int xxxx();
```